# PHP delete the contents of a directory

Tags: php, directory, delete-file

How do I do that? Is there any method provided by kohana 3?

Comment: It's a PHP framework, although this question doesn't really have anything to do with it, retagged.

Answer (score 10):

To delete a directory and all this content, you'll have to write some recursive deletion function -- or use one that already exists.

You can find some examples in the user's notes on the documentation page of [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir) ; for instance, here's [the one proposed by bcairns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#92661) in august 2009 *(quoting)* :

```
<?php
// ensure $dir ends with a slash
function delTree($dir) {
    $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK );
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' )
            delTree( $file );
        else
            unlink( $file );
    }
    rmdir( $dir );
}
?>
```

Comment: $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK ); -> Please explain this line. Thanks.

Comment: The `glob` function *(see http://php.net/glob )* will return all files that match the pattern -- and `*` will match all files, which means glob will return a list of all files in the directory pointed by `$dir` ;; `GLOB_MARK` means "*Adds a slash to each directory returned*"

Comment: And if you want to delete just the contents of the folder - not the folder itself - remove the `rmdir( $dir );` line

Comment: Also, you can add `GLOB_NOSORT` to speed up removal a bit, so it would be `$files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK | GLOB_NOSORT );`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this way, simple and direct.

```
    $files = glob('your/folder/' . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            self::deleteDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried unlink in the directory ?

```
      chdir("file");
   foreach (glob("N*") as $filename )
      {
        unlink($filename);
      }
```

This deletes filenames starting from N

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Kohana 3, but I'd use a `DirectoryIterator()` and `unlink()` in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Pascal does not work on all OS. Therefor I have created another solution. The code is part of a static class library and is static.

It deletes all files and directories in a given parent directory.

The function is recursive for the subdirectories and has an option not to delete the parent directory ($keepFirst).

If the parent directory does not exist or is not a directory 'null' is returned. In case of a successful deletion 'true' is returned.

```
/**
* Deletes all files in the given directory, also the subdirectories.
* @param string  $dir       Name of the directory
* @param boolean $keepFirst [Optional] indicator for first directory.
* @return null | true
*/
public static function deltree( $dir, $keepFirst = false ) {
  // First check if it is a directory.
  if (! is_dir( $dir ) ) {
     return null;
  }

  if ($handle = opendir( $dir ) ) {
     while (false !== ( $fileName = readdir($handle) ) ) {
        // Skips the hidden directory files.
        if ($fileName == "." || $fileName == "..") {
           continue;
        }

        $dpFile = sprintf( "%s/%s", $dir, $fileName );

        if (is_dir( $dpFile ) ) {
           self::deltree( $dpFile );
        } else {
           unlink( $dpFile );
        }
     }  // while

     // Directory removal, optional not the parent directory.
     if (! $keepFirst ) {
        rmdir( $dir );
     }
  }  // if
  return true;
}  // deltree
```

Comment: What OSes are not covered with Pascal's solution?

Comment: Thanks, missed that