# How to disable created cache files at cache/dwoo/compiled folder on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, dwoo

I've got serious problem with my storage on web hosting because of a lot of cache files that created on  at cache/dwoo/compiled folder. I developed my website using codeigniter framework. I want to disable this feature (auto created cache files  at cache/dwoo/compiled folder), because it using a lot of space on my storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Dwoo are you using?

According to [this thread](http://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/3229), Version 1.2.0 fixes this issue.

Comment: i used version 1.1.0, should i upgrade to 1.2.0?

Comment: the version that mentioned on the thread that you told me before is CodeIgniter version right? I thought it's DWOO version, because the newest version of DWOO is 1.1.1 (not 1.2.0).

i've try to upgrade the DWOO library first, but nothing change, the cache files still created automatically..

so i think i should to upgrade my codeigniter..I hope it can solve my problem..

thanks dude, for your information..I'll give another feedback after i upgrade my codeigniter.

Comment: after i look out my codeigniter version, it's 2.0 and I was upgrade it to 2.0.1 and again, nothing change.. :(
is there anyway to disable this dwoo? I'm so desperate about it, delete all cache files manually everyday, such a dummy things.. :'(

Comment: simple solution: set up a Cron Job to remove them for you.

Comment: what is that? can you tell me where i can find out about that?
btw, sorry about my English :p hehe

Comment: Wikipedia says: *cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. cron enables users to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at certain times or dates.* ... Your web host probably gives you the ability to set up these jobs. Search your web hosts' control panel. Basically you set up a reoccurring .php script to be called. Inside that .php script you have code that clears a specific directory. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2205187/568884) for potential scripts.